# Why starting firefox (from command line) in VM starts the firefox in the host machine and vice-versa?

Tags: ssh, firefox

I have a SLED 10 host machine and I am using a SLES 10 VM via `ssh -X`.

When I start `firefox` in my VM using `firefox &` then it runs the `firefox` which is installed in the VM. So that's fine.

However, if my host machine's `firefox` is running, and then I start VM's `firefox`, then instead of starting its own, a new session of host's `firefox` starts running.

Same happens the opposite way also, if VM's `firefox` is running then I am not able to start host's `firefox`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because for some reason, the firefox devs have decided that is a good idea. In fact, they are so sure this is a feature and not a bug, they have even provided an option to disable it. Try running

```
firefox -no-remote
```

That should cause a new instance to be started on the remote machine. For (a tiny bit of) more info, try `firefox -h`:

```
-no-remote         Do not accept or send remote commands; implies -new-instance.
-new-instance      Open new instance, not a new window in running instance.
```

This had me [completely baffled](https://superuser.com/q/462055/151431) for a while and I still don't understand why (or, for that matter, how) they do this.

Comment: Thanks! it helped. I never knew my question had so many duplicates, I thought there must be some problem with my versions of firefox ('cos I am using very old versions)